# jQuery Dailog add row to table - scope issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am adding rows(from json response) to a table inside my dailog:

```
$.each(result.data, function (i, item) {    
            trHTML += '<tr>'+ //tr start
                //data
                '<td><button onclick="vm.addStock(this)">add<button/></td>' +
                '<td>' + item.bName + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + item.Key + '</td>'+
                '<td>' + item.ItemType + '</td>'+
                '<td>' + local + '</td>' +
                '</tr>'; // tr ends
              });
              $('#serachTableResult').append(trHTML);
```

when the user click the `button` inside the first `td` I ant the function inside to run but it is `undefined`:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: addStock is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (FPFEquities:1)
```

The function is in the same scope that opens the dailog, other buttons on the dailog works.
The dailog:

```
    $("#addNewStock").dialog({
        autoOpen : false,
        modal : true,
        dialogClass : 'everdialog_1',
        title : 'add',
        buttons :  
            [{
                    text: "search",
                    id: "addNewPaperToProtfolio",
                    click: function(){
                        //sending search query to server
                        vm.submitSerachQuery(this); //vm is my scope object
                    }
                },{
                    text: "close",
                    click: function(){
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    }

                }] 
    });
```

And the opening button:

```
vm.addNewStockToProtfolio = function() 
    $("#addNewStock").dialog("open");
};
```

Comment: We'll need to see the rest of your code

Comment: Adding the dailog as well.

Comment: Do you have a definition of `vm.addStock`? because `$("#addNewStock").dialog` does not count

Comment: Of course as I said it is in the same scope(vm).

Comment: Are `addStock` and `addNewStockToProtfolio` supposed to be the same function?

Comment: You might also like to try changing the `onclick` listener to `console.log(vm)`, check that `vm` really is what you're expecting.